# Using Jsoup to parse html

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

theFirst off I am very new to coding in java, and I am using Android Studio.  I am using Jsoup to go to a URL and grab the HTML source code. My code successfully does this, now I need to parse the HTML for one specific line.  The string I need from the HTML contains a link, but I do not need the address of the link just the string that is displayed as the link.  This is the code from the class I am using to accomplish this:

```
private class FetchAnton extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String price;
    String url = "http://www.antoncoop.com/markets/cash.php";
    Elements hrefEles;
    String value = null;
    String html = null;
    Document doc = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            //Connect to website
            html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().toString();

            if (html != null && html.length() > 0) {
                doc = Jsoup.parse(html);           
                if (doc != null) {
                    /** Get all A tag element with HREF attribute like '/markets/cashchart.php?c=2246' **/
                    hrefEles = doc.select("a[href*=/markets/cashchart.php?c=2246]");

                    if (hrefEles != null && hrefEles.size() > 0) {
                        for (Element e: hrefEles) {
                            //value = e.ownText();
                           // break;
                        }

                        price = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the section HTML that I am interested in:

```
</table>
<br />
<table class="homepage_quoteboard" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr class="section">
<td colspan="10">Wheat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%">Name</td>
<td width="10%">Delivery</td>
<td width="10%">Delivery End</td>
<td width="10%">Futures Month</td>
<td width="10%" align="right">Futures Price</td>
<td width="10%" align="right">Change</td>
<td width="10%" align="right">Basis</td>
<td width="10%" align="right">Cash Price</td>
<td width="10%" align="right">Settlement</td>
<td width="10%">Notes</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<script language="javascript">          
writeBidRow('Wheat',-60,false,false,false,0.5,'01/15/2015','02/26/2015','All','&nbsp;','&nbsp;',60,'even','c=2246&l=3519&d=G15',quotes['KEH15'], 0-0);
writeBidRow('Wheat',-65,false,false,false,0.5,'07/01/2015','07/31/2015','All','&nbsp;','&nbsp;',60,'odd','c=2246&l=3519&d=N15',quotes['KEN15'], 0-0);
</script>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The only thing I am interested in is getting the $4.91 as the string called "price". It is in the line of HTML code that is indented farthest to the right. Can anyone tell me what code to use to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this A tag have any other attribute apart from href, for example a classname or id?

Comment: I believe the class name is "even".

Answer (score 0):

Everything is described clearly in the following source codes with comments.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String value = null;
    String html = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Elements hrefEles = null;

    try {
        //Connect to website
        html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().toString();

        if (html != null && html.length() > 0) {
            doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

            if (doc != null) {
                /** Get all A tag element with HREF attribute like '/markets/cashchart.php?c=2246' **/
                hrefEles = doc.select("a[href*=/markets/cashchart.php?c=2246]"); 

                if (hrefEles != null && hrefEles.size() > 0) {
                    for (Element e: hrefEles) {
                        value = e.ownText();
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("value: " + value);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am still having trouble.  I need to implement this within a private class.  I will edit my post to show the code for the entire class.  I altered my class based on what you posted here, but I still got an empty string returned.  Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I added my original code before I altered it after reading your help because I just got really confused after I changed it lol.  I really appreciate your help, and cannot thank you enough.

Comment: I am still having trouble...I am getting a blank string returned.  I stopped the execution of the code at a certain line and displayed the html file to the screen.  And it looks like the html file on the phone screen is not identical to the html that I got from my browser.  The html I posted I got from the DOM Explorer in the developer tools in IE 11.  Looks like I will have to keep trying tomorrow, but thank you very much for you help, I am sure your code will work for me once I figure out what's going on with the differences in html. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Update me again here if you need help. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, the first question I have is the "hrefEles" in your code threw an error, to fix it I declared a variable at the top of the class as such: Elements hrefEles;.  Is that the appropriate thing to do?  I also updated my original post with the HTML portion with the appropriate section of code that my phone is showing.  Now the part of the html I am after is whatever value represents the "quotes['KEH15']".  It is in the updated html code if you scroll all the way to the right.  I have also updated the java code to what I currently have.  Sorry for asking you to redo your code three times.  Thanks

Comment: Declaring hrefEles is correct, my bad here. Seems like the HTML page you are querying has a portion of javascript code which will only be executed once the page finish loading, and the value you are after is the quotes['KEH15'] which is also part of the javascript itself. Then we will have a problem here. JSoup is just an HTML parser which does not execute javascript, hence there is no way JSoup can retrieve the value of quotes['KEH15'].

Comment: Well darn.  I will have to find another way.  Thank you very much for all your help, im sure some of your code will still help me.  Thank you for taking the time to write it